# C# Putting an Array in to a String Backward

Tags: c#, arrays, string, join

So i have an Array wich i filled up .
Now the problem i have is i wanna put the array together in to one string but starting from the end of the Array.

```
while(Opsplitser > -1)
{
    EindResultaat = EindResultaat + string.Join(" ",  Opsplitsen[Opsplitser]);
    Opsplitser--;

}
```

I have used as Code  but the problem i have is that the join puts the whole array eventually in one big string but doesnt put a Whitespace in between the text of the arrays.
is there a different way i can use to put the array in to one string whit the Spaces in between?

Comment: Read the documentation for String.Join(). It doesn't do what you think it does. It does something totally different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
string str = string.Join(" ", Opsplitsen.Reverse());
```

The Linq operation `Reverse()` inverts the direction of the items in the array and `Join` with a whitespace as first parameter joins the items with a whitespace between all items.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Join twice, and use LINQ's Reverse method to get rid of the outer loop, like this:

```
var res = string.Join(" "
,   listOfLists.Reverse().Select(list => 
        string.Join(" ", list)
     )
);
```

Comment: Why the extra comma's in the result?

Comment: @MartinMulder I see, he used space for his inner lists, too!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
string result;
string[] input;
for(int i = input.Lenght; i >= 0; i--)
{
   result += input[i];
   result += (i == 0) ? '' : ' ';
}
```

Comment: No. Swap the two concatination lines.

Comment: if i == 0 I dont want to add the blank .. ?

Comment: True. The line is correct, but you want to add the seperating space between the previous word and the current word. You do NOT want to add the space AFTER you have already added the current word, because their might not be a next word...

Comment: I add 'A' then SPACE then 'B' then SPACE then 'C' what is wrong there ? @MartinMulder

Comment: You are totally right. I just came how, had some wine, and everything is clearer now. My mistake.

Comment: @MartinMulder haha ^^ no worries bro